# Rails FormBuilder submit text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am  doing what this says: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit

However, it works on some computers and not in others (it uses default labels). What could be the cause?

This is my en.yml

```
en:
  hello: "Hello world"

en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Crear"
      update: "Editar"

en:
  images:
  errors:
    messages:
       extension_white_list_error: 'Favor seleccionar una imagen (jpg jpeg gif png)'
```

The last error message works as expected.

Comment: What exactly works on 'some computers'?

Answer (score 0):

The default value for submit buttons is both dependant on the browser and the locale of the browser / operating system.

Rails does not reload locale files automatically. You need to restart your server to see the changes.

But why on earth are you adding spanish translations to your english locale file? It defeats the whole purpose of I18n.

```
# es.yml
es:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Crear"
      update: "Editar"
```

And follow the steps on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html to setup your the default locale in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did try that, config.i18n.default_locale = :es, but it still outputs the text in English. It is a simple app and I just need it for the buttons text, so I figured just overriding the default en would work. It used to at first, but now out of nowhere, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, even with changing the locale to es.  The problem in both cases was that I was putting two times en: or es: for different messages, and rails only obeyed the last one in the file, ignoring the rest, That is why the last message worked, but not the first, and why it worked at first but not after adding the last messages.

Thanks for the help.